# Facebook Subscriptions API - Push notifications for comments on pages?

Tags: php, facebook, api, push, subscription

The subscriptions API on the Facebook REST documentation looks, like they would allow me to get Push notifications, whenever something is changed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/

According to the documentation on the page, I can subscribe to the feed connection of the page object:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ (There is no asterisk).

But I don't understand which pages will send me notifications and what happens in general.

When I tried to implement this with a test subscription for the user wall and page feed, I did get notifications when something was changed on the users wall, but not for the page.

Do you have any experience with the Subscriptions API from Facebook?

Comment: Did you had any progress in here? I'd like to hear more about this subject. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

I can't tell why you didn't receive a page post depending on your information, but if you received the real time updates, you will see that the request will have a content type of `application/json` and the body will contain a `pageid`  that has changed.

So it's really not a problem that you can't tell which page has changed.